# Not a valid month but Number datatype Java-Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlexception

I try to collect some information from database Oracle through Java.

The string that i execute is:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=? ";

try (PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql)
{
pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(stringDateThatGetsFromUser))
 try(ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery()){ //throws exception
.......
}}
```

The exception thrown is

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

> Caused by: Error : 1843, Position : 1440, Sql = SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=:1 , OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=?, Error Msg = ORA-01843: not a valid month

AN example of ref month that i set is '202101'. In Oracle it is a NUMBER(10) data type not a DATE.

I also tried to execute as some other post on 'not valid month' suggested.

```
      connection.createStatement().execute("alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYYMM'");
```

The exception changed to:

> Caused by: Error : 1858, Position : 1440, Sql = SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=:1 , OriginalSql = SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=?, Error Msg = ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I have also tried TO_NUMBER(?,'999999') with setString. Same error as previous.

When i execute though Oracle the following, it runs ok.

```
SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH='202101';
```

****************************UPDATE*************************

i dont know why but this works through Java, but it gives zero results.

```
 String sql="SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH='20210101'";
```

Comment: REF_MONTH is date column ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the Java code where you set the bind parameter's value. Do you use `PreparedStatement.setInt()` or `PreparedStatement.setDate()` or something else?

Comment: ref month is a number(10) not a date column. It's already in the description. Not valid month makes no sense.

Comment: Did you first try `SELECT * FROM SAP_PHOTOVOLTAIC WHERE REF_MONTH=202101`? Also validate user input: `stringDateThatGetsFromUser.matches("\\d{6}")`

Comment: @JoopEggen String matches and the select gives result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed. We found the error. The sql code of the table in the database wasn't properly modified for some values in two columns.